# Install fonts in Linux container for ASP.NET Core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

From Visual Studio, I've created a default ASP.NET Core Web Application with enabled Docker support.
It's using the default [Microsoft Offical image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/official-net-docker-images) for Linux container.

Here is my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication1.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApplication1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

I want to install *Microsoft Windows Fonts* on it, I tried the following but it's not working:

```
RUN apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

How can I install fonts on this container?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I need them so that I can generate PDF files. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Got it. Revise the start of your Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

#Add these two lines
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
[...]
```

The first line updates the default */etc/apt/sources.list* file in the Linux OS to include the 'contrib' archive area (which is where [ttf-mscorefonts-installer](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) lives). That ensures apt-get can find it and install it as normal in the second line (along with fontconfig, which you'll also need.)

For the record, [this page](https://packages.debian.org/buster/ttf-mscorefonts-installer) suggested using the "fonts-liberation" package instead of ttf-mscorefonts-installer, which you can also get working with two *different* lines at the start of the Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

#Add these two lines for fonts-liberation instead
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y fontconfig fonts-liberation
RUN fc-cache -f -v

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

[...]
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is how I did it for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-preview which is based on Debian 12:

```
RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ bookworm-security main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i'.bak' 's/$/ contrib/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer fontconfig
```

Comment: Thank you for that. This should be the correct answer for .NET 8

Answer (score 5):

you can copy your custom fonts to the docker images and install fonts like this

```
RUN apt-get -y install fontconfig
COPY /fonts ~/.fonts
COPY /fonts /usr/shared/fonts
COPY /fonts /usr/share/fonts/truetype
# refresh system font cache
RUN fc-cache -f -v
```

or if you want to install microsoft trueType core fonts. you can do like this

```
RUN echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends fontconfig ttf-mscorefonts-installer
# refresh system font cache
RUN fc-cache -f -v
```

you can use this sample dockerfile too
[DockerFile](https://github.com/captnswing/msttcorefonts/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately it didn't install _ttf-mscorefonts-installer_. Did you try using this with ASP.NET Core application? Can you perhaps show me the _Dockerfile_ that is working for you?

Comment: I still doesn't work. I see that the _Dockerfile_ you linked is using Ubuntu container. I'm not sure that this is the case with the default container image for ASP.NET Core. Again, have you tried this with ASP.NET Core, does it work for you?

Comment: @hertzogth - did you ever get this working?  Im stuck on the exact same problem and nothing seems to work

Comment: @Jonesie no, I was unable to install those fonts. In my use case I was able to avoid this issue by embedding the font files into my application.

Answer (score 1):

Working example with linux alpine docker since other answers dont work.
[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438257/how-to-install-microsoft-true-type-font-on-alpine-linux/438269)

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig && \
    update-ms-fonts && \
    fc-cache -f
```

Comment: I vote it but not working with persian fonts

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the fonts (from my Windows dev machine) to a ./fonts folder under the api project.  Then in Dockerfile I copy and configure these thusly:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base

# not sure we need all of these
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y libicu-dev libharfbuzz0b libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 fontconfig

...

RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release  -r linux-x64 -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ms
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/fonts .
RUN fc-cache -f -v

...
```

I guess it would be better if I could use the fonts without having to copy thing to /usr/share.

Despite many web sites describing the process I couldn't get ttf-mscorefonts-installer to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did in `.NET 7` with `alpine` image base.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
RUN apk add font-dejavu #--> Install any font of your choice
RUN fc-cache -f -v
```

You can find the font names from the following [alpine linux fonts link](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Fonts)

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was this:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one want to install fonts in runtime,You can run this method before use;

```cs
/// <summary>
/// init fonts file in linux and return ttf file path
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resourcePath"></param>
/// <param name="_logger"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<string> InitFonts(string resourcePath,ILogger _logger)
{
    _logger.LogTrace("start init fonts");


    const string fontsPath = "/usr/share/fonts";
    if (!Directory.Exists(fontsPath))
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("the path of:/usr/share/fonts is not exist ignore init");
        return new List<string>();
    }

    var groupBuyingPath = Path.Combine(fontsPath, "groupbuying");

    var pfRegular = Path.Combine(groupBuyingPath, "PingFang-SC-Regular.ttf");
    var pfMedium = Path.Combine(groupBuyingPath, "PingFang-SC-Medium.ttf");
    var alibaba = Path.Combine(groupBuyingPath, "Alibaba-PuHuiTi-M.ttf");
    if (File.Exists(pfRegular))
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("the file:{path}  is exist ignore init", pfRegular);
        return new List<string>();
    }

    if (!Directory.Exists(groupBuyingPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(groupBuyingPath);
        _logger.LogTrace("auto create fonts folder in :{path}", fontsPath);
    }

    File.Copy(Path.Combine(resourcePath, "Fonts", "PingFang-SC-Regular.ttf"), pfRegular);
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(resourcePath, "Fonts", "PingFang-SC-Medium.ttf"), pfMedium);
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(resourcePath, "Fonts","Alibaba-PuHuiTi-M.ttf"),alibaba);

    _logger.LogTrace("ttf file copy success");

    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "mkfontscale",
        WorkingDirectory = groupBuyingPath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = psi
    };

    proc.Start();   
    var psi1 = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "mkfontdir",
        WorkingDirectory = groupBuyingPath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    var proc1 = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = psi1
    };

    proc1.Start();   
    var psi2 = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "fc-cache",
        WorkingDirectory = groupBuyingPath,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    var proc2 = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = psi2
    };

    proc2.Start();

    _logger.LogTrace("run command success");

    return new List<string>() {pfRegular, pfMedium, alibaba};
}
```

This answer:[.net core(system.drawing.common) not able to render chinese and arabic fonts on linux docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77499071/7960551)
has  more description

Comment: code comments on Stack Overflow must be written in english.